# wordpress redirect users to the same URL they request appending parameters according to role

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am working on a Wordpress website with multiple roles. My target is to redirect user with a specific role when they request pages like orders in the admin area to go to a filtered URL having their id.

example: User requests: [www.site.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order](http://www.site.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order)

```
     User redirects to: www.site.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order&wcb2bsa_sales_agent_search={current user id}
```

This Applies only to the role "tester"

My Approach was:

```
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'only_let_user_see', 10, 3 );
function only_let_user_see( $allcaps, $cap, $args ) {  
if($args[0] === 'edit_posts' && is_admin()) {
$url = "https://";
$url.= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$url.= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url.= 'wcb2bsa_sales_agent_search='; 
$url.= '100'; //fixed number for test purpose
} 
if(current_user_can('tester')) { 
wp_redirect ($url); 
exit; 
}else
{ return $allcaps;}}
```

Rewriting the code now gave me error, Although when I was testing it it just worked but the problem was that user receives error: Too many redirects.

I really need help with this, So any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `user_has_cap` filter in which user capabilities are required to return. In your code, you are redirecting the `tester` user without passing capabilities so instead, you should use `admin_init` action in order to redirect the user.

```
function redirect_users_by_role() {
    global $pagenow;
    if ($pagenow == 'edit.php' && $_REQUEST['post_type'] == 'shop_order' && current_user_can('shop_manager')) {
        $url = "https://";
        $url.= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $url.= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $url.= '&wcb2bsa_sales_agent_search='; 
        $url.= '100'; //fixed number for test purpose
        wp_redirect ($url); 
        exit;
    } 
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'redirect_users_by_role' );
```

The above code is tested and working fine!